# How to remove unwanted gap between the border and the element

Tags: css, sass

I have the following pen:

http://codepen.io/Bodokh/pen/EZKxjE

And I have some cool buttons I made. Now the problem is that when the button is active and scales down just a little, a strange white gap appears between the button border and background color that zoomed in.

on the left of the following image is the button at its normal state, in the middle button that is focused, hovered and active, and on the far right a focused and hovered button.

[image: my buttons]

As you can see when the button is active a strange white gap appears, I tried the following to correct the problem without success

on the pseudo element that zooms the background color:

```
transform:scale(1.1);
```

And on the parent element:

```
overflow:hidden;
```

But that didn't help since overflow only hides the content overflowing the padding and not the border.

So the question is what's way to workaround this?

Button's HTML:

```
<button class="zoombtn">
    <span>GREY<span>
</button>
```

Button's source code in SCSS:

```
.zoombtn{
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family:'Roboto','Open Sans Hebrew','Arial',sans-serif;
    margin:6px;
    cursor:pointer;
    font-size:32px;
    padding:24px;
    border:0;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,.07);
    position:relative;
    outline:0;
    border-width:6px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:#BDBDBD;       
    transition:all .25s;
    overflow:hidden;
    span{
        position:relative;
        color:#424242;
        transition:all .25s cubic-bezier(.55,0,.1,1);
    }
    &:before{
        content:' ';
        display:block;
        position:absolute;
        top:0;left:0;right:0;bottom:0;
        background:#9E9E9E;
        transform:scale(0);
        transition:all .25s cubic-bezier(.55,0,.1,1);
    }
    &:hover,&:focus{
        border-color:#9E9E9E;
                box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgba(0,0,0,0.25), 0 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);
        span{
            color:#fff;
            text-shadow:0 0 5px #555;
        }
        &:before{
            transform:scale(1.1);
        }
    }
    &:active{
        box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.23);
        transform:scale(.97);
        border-color:#757575;
        span{
            text-shadow:0 2px 8px #333;
        }
        &:before{
            background:#757575;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide all relevant code in an [mcve] in the question itself, not on a third-party site.

Comment: can't replicate it, does it happen in a particular browser or do I have to do something special to see it? off the top of my head, my guess would be to disable the border on hover and let the background on the pseudo element color the box.

Comment: @MichaelCoker What browser do you use? I tried this on Edge, and chrome and the problem is consistent on both browsers. I can just remove the border on hover and add some padding but the animation won't look as good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a very simple answer to my own question. By simply adding the following line to the active state of the button:

```
.zoombtn:active{
    background:{background_of_button}
}
```

And that basically solves the problem because the white gap becomes a colored gap.

The gap is still there but just the same color as the button so it isn't noticeable at all.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a clipping issue associated with `overflow:hidden` on the button element. You don't really need it, just delete that line and the artifact will disappear.

Comment: Removing the overflow does not change the outcome, but I did post a very simple solution the problem. Thanks for the effort though.

Comment: It does for me.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like :

`transform:scale(.97)` could be turned to `transform: perspective(500px) translate3d(0px,0px,-10px);` for `.zoombtn:active` (`&:active`).

[fork of your pen fixed](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wgGKqW)

Comment: That would remove the whole active click effect animation. I have posted my answer above either way so thanks anyways!

Comment: @Bodokh ?? how much difference from 0.97 to 1, beside filling the whole element and not showing the gap, does it make ? 0.03% ... 1pixel average . I linked a fork of the pen, possible i missed something, let me know :):

Comment: If you enter the link and have a look you will see the .97 does add quite a bit.

Comment: @Bodokh oh yes, i updated link and answer to make still usefull with a 3d approach ;)

Comment: Though it is pretty neat , it's a little buggy, try clicking very fast on a button, sometimes it scales down too much, and still wouldn't solve the border problem to the end. On chrome at least, some buttons still have protruding white space on the right of the button when active.

Comment: @Bodokh okay, could not reproduce what you explain on my window7 and last Chrome, it only comes to select everything at one point clicking too much too fast :) . thanks for the feedback.